# Django Model Form is not saving data to database, but object is created

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm using a model form and a class based view and I'm trying to save user post model to db. The problem is that UserPost object is created (I've printed it in console and it has all the data and every time when I create new it has new id, so it seems it works) but nothing is saved to database. I'm not sure where the problem might be. Do you have any idea?

**views.py**

```
class CompletePost(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post_form=myForms.UploadPostForm()
        return render(request,'shop/create_post.html',{'post_form':post_form})
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post_form=myForms.UploadPostForm(request.POST)
        print(request.user.id)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            user_post_v=post_form.save()
            transaction.commit()
```

**models.py**

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    user_id=models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text=models.TextField(null=True)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    is_used=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
    def get_absolute_url(self,**kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('index')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `FormView` for views with forms:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView

class CompletePost(FormView):
    template_name = 'your_template.html'
    form_class = UploadPostForm
    
    def form_valid():
        new_post = form.save(commit=False)
        category = Category.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']) # or just query your category the way you would do it
        user = self.request.user
        new_post.category = category
        new_post.user_id = user
        new_post.save()
        return redirect('index') # or wherever you wanna redirect after submitting
```

Comment: I wrote code like you said but it's still not working, just creating a object and that's all

Comment: you also need to assign a category in the same way you assign a user, better way is to use `FormView` from `django.views.generic`, I'll update the answer

Comment: It worked with generic CreateView for example, but I have a plan to add another form in this view to upload multiple images so that's why I'm not using it. Idk if it's because of class based view or something....It also didn't work with CreateWithInlinesView for the same reason-it's not being saved to db

Comment: if you want multiple forms try using `Formsets`, heres the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I tried, but the same thing is happening..... Thank you! :)

Comment: No, I said thank you for suggestions you gave me, but the same is still happening :)

Comment: Can you add your Account model and UserPost form to the question?

Comment: I just realized that I somehow didn't see new records in db, I don't know how... It work, thank you! :D

Comment: ok... you can accept the answer if you want, maybe it will help someone

Comment: I just did, it'll maybe save someone's time :D